# nfs-mounted writeable drive: new folders have no permissions

Tags: permissions, linux-mint, mount, nfs

I am using Linux Mint 13.

There is a folder on a local network which I'm mapping to a local mount point with nfs, like so:

```
sudo mount.nfs -rw 192.168.18.13:/volume1/resource_library /mnt/resource_library_writeable
```

If I then create a new folder called "foo" inside this directory, using my desktop tools (so not sudo-ing), it has no permissions:

```
$ ls -l  /mnt/resource_library_writeable
....
drwxr-xr-x  3 1024 users 4096 May 12 14:05 flute and clarinet
d---------  2 1024 users 4096 Oct 25 12:25 foo
drwxrwxr-x 39 1024 users 4096 May 19 10:17 general
....
```

I've shown a couple of its sibling folders here.

My username is `max`, and group is `max`.  The username and group on these folders are "1024" and "users", respectively.

If I log onto the source drive with ssh, then "users" is the groupname there too (and the user is the one I log in as, which isn't 1024).  So, i suppose that the nfs connection logs me in as user 1024, maybe?

Is there something else I need to do when I mount it to make it so that I can edit it normally, as if it was a regular folder?

EDIT: as requested, the /etc/exports file on the source host

```
$ sudo cat /etc/exports
/volume1/NAS    192.168.18.0/24(ro,async,no_wdelay,root_squash,insecure_locks,sec=sys,anonuid=1025,anongid=100)
/volume1/resource_library   192.168.18.1/24(rw,async,no_wdelay,insecure,all_squash,insecure_locks,sec=sys,anonuid=1024,anongid=100)
/volume1/web    192.168.18.1/24(rw,async,no_wdelay,insecure,all_squash,insecure_locks,sec=sys,anonuid=1024,anongid=100)
/volume1/resource_library   192.168.18.1/24(ro,async,no_wdelay,insecure,all_squash,insecure_locks,sec=sys,anonuid=1024,anongid=100)
```

Comment: Can you show us the `/etc/exports` file on 192.168.18.13?

Comment: Your server's export list has the `all_squash` and `anonuid=1024,anongid=100` options. If you can explain what kind of access you'd like remote users to have, we can help you pick the appropriate options. Run [`man exports`](https://linux.die.net/man/5/exports) to see what each option does.

Comment: Thanks Mark.  I'm the only user connecting via linux.  A few other users connect on Windows and Mac via SMB.  The main thing I want is for all files and folders I create, outside of sudo mode, to have 775 permissions.  thanks!

Comment: I can't explain how the mount and exports options you have would result in a directory being created with 000 permissions. Does directory `foo` have those same permissions if you `ls` it while logged into the server?

Comment: If you don't need `all_squash`, remove it. When present, it makes all remote users, regardless of uid and gid, get mapped to the anon uid and gid. The option is useful if you want all remote users to have the same access to files and directories on the filesystem, but it looks like that's not what you want. But check with the person who added that option.

Comment: I will, when he comes back from holiday :) It might just be a default that hasn't really been thought about at all.  thanks

Comment: In response to the permissions on the remote drive for "foo" - i just did this experiment again and the new folder (at my end *and* the remote end) has 755 on it.  Weird.  I think it's because in the meantime, I did this on the remote drive:  `sudo chmod -R 775 /volume1/resource_library`, and that's made new subfolders pick up a "looser" permission.  it's weird though because this chmod command is done on the remote drive routinely, so i'd expect it to have had either 775 or 755 already.